# Expression is not in GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate

I have a log table in MySQL (v5.7) that records user requests from which I extract a breakdown of activity showing the number of users and total hits for each month e.g.:

```
Date            Users   Hits
September 2018  20      1,839
August 2018     23      2,723
July 2018       21      1,632
June 2018       22      2,981
```

This is currently achieved using the following query:

```
SELECT month(l.time) m, year(l.time) y, date_format(l.time, '%M %Y') monthyear, 
  (select count(distinct userid) from log lm 
    where month(lm.time) = month(l.time) and year(lm.time) = year(l.time)) users,
  count(u.name) hits
FROM log l left join users u on u.id=l.userid
group by date_format(l.time, '%M %Y')
order by l.time desc, l.id desc
```

This SQL fails with only_full_group_by enabled, as is now the default in MySQL, because not all expressions are in the GROUP BY clause. The solutions I have found typically involve either using an aggregate function such as MAX() or adding all expressions to the GROUP BY clause, but the 'users' subquery is making those approaches problematic: I can't use the MAX() approach (invalid syntax) and adding it to the GROUP BY clause results in a query so slow that I haven't yet seen a test complete.

I feel there is probably solution that's elegant and performant without resorting to disabling only_full_group_by, but I'm out of my limited depth with SQL.

Comment: Kinda funny...it was predicted that mysql implementing proper Group By constraints would reveal a slew of horrible code.  Consider the rewrite option in this case as the subselect syntax is a real poor approach to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(l.time, '%M %Y') AS monthyear, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT l.userid) AS users,
  COUNT(*) AS hits
FROM log l
GROUP BY monthyear
```

You don't need the individual month or year in your select-list because you don't show it in the desired result.

You don't need to join to the `users` table at all, unless you mean to count only hits on users with a non-NULL `name` column (COUNT ignores NULLs, and I would guess you mean to count all hits from the log, which means you should use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(u.name)`.

I removed the ORDER BY clause, because it referenced columns that aren't in the result. If you want to order by monthyear, you should consider formatting the monthyear in a way that sorts the way you want:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(l.time, '%Y-%m') AS monthyear, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT l.userid) AS users,
  COUNT(*) AS hits
FROM log l
GROUP BY monthyear
```

The GROUP BY will by default order the groups by value.

Comment: Thanks - couldn't see the wood for the trees!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want to use a subquery for this. Doesn't this do what you want?

```
SELECT month(l.time) as m, year(l.time) as y, date_format(l.time, '%M %Y') as monthyear, 
       count(distinct l.userid) as users,
       count(u.name) as hits
FROM log l left join
     users u
     on u.id = l.userid
GROUP BY m, y, monthyear
ORDER BY max(l.time) desc, l.id desc;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a bit of a blind spot when it comes to SQL! This was from some quite old code, I don't know whether I cobbled it together or someone provided it for me but it was clearly very ugly and inefficient.